200k worth of neiro tokens stuck in the wlf contract
I accidentally sent the wrong coins (NEIRO) to my contract (WLF). Is there any way to retrieve them? (worth $200k right now)
From what I saw in the contract, there is only the manual swap option, but it only supports the native coin.
Is this correct, or am I overlooking something?
If anyone can help me with this, I will immediately send 5% of the coins as a thank you (currently worth 10k USD).
https://etherscan.io/address/0xda0c0d0a0ff8262f3ee9ee8a712b988df897be65#code
wlf ca: 0xda0c0D0a0FF8262F3EE9Ee8A712B988Df897bE65
neiro ca: 0x812ba41e071c7b7fa4ebcfb62df5f45f6fa853ee

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any "emergency" ERC-20 retrieval functions in the contract, meaning the tokens are permanently lost.
I know this can be frustrating but hopefully, you can use this as a learning experience and won't make the same mistake again in the future.
